# Layout issues using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I want to make an application which would look more or less look like the picture below:

[image]

I have written the code for top `JPanel` but I don't get the results as excepted. My output is like this:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends JPanel {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Main().frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        frameinit();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void frameinit() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Tool Title");
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 800));
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1000,800));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c;
        JLabel LTitle,Lcus,Lmode,Lsc,Lcorbank,Lavd,Lrate,Lcrate,Lvaldate,Lbc,Lr;
        JTextField Tcus,Tmode,Tsc,Tcorbank,Tavd,Trate,Tcrate,Tvaldate,Tbc,Tr;
        LTitle = new JLabel("Title");
        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        c.gridwidth=4;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(LTitle, c);
        Lcus = new JLabel("Customer");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lcus, c);
        Lmode = new JLabel("Mode");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lmode, c);
        Lsc = new JLabel("Sell Ccy");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=3;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lsc, c);
        Lcorbank = new JLabel("Correspondant Bank");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=4;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lcorbank, c);
        Lavd = new JLabel("Amount Value Date");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=5;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lavd, c);
        Lrate = new JLabel("Rate");
        c.gridx=2;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lrate, c);
        Lcrate = new JLabel("Coverage Rate");
        c.gridx=2;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lcrate, c);
        Lavd = new JLabel("Value Date");
        c.gridx=2;
        c.gridy=3;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lavd, c);
        Lbc = new JLabel("Buy Ccy");
        c.gridx=2;
        c.gridy=4;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lbc, c);
        Lr = new JLabel("Remarks");
        c.gridx=2;
        c.gridy=5;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Lr, c);
        Tcus = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tcus, c);
        Tmode = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tmode, c);
        Tsc = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=3;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tsc, c);
        Tcorbank = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=4;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tcorbank, c);
        Tavd = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=1;
        c.gridy=5;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tavd, c);
        Trate = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=4;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Trate, c);
        Tcrate = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=4;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tcrate, c);
        Tvaldate = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=4;
        c.gridy=3;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tvaldate, c);
        Tbc = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=4;
        c.gridy=4;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tbc, c);
        Tr = new JTextField();
        c.gridx=4;
        c.gridy=5;
        c.gridwidth=1;
        c.gridheight=1;
        add(Tr, c);
    }

}
```

Comment: From the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html): "Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the center of their container.". Also you might want to set some values to `anchor` and `fill`.

Comment: wow its working. thanks DSquare. i dint added anchor and fill, i just added weightx and weight to 1. and it worked thanks bro. and can u tell me what to keep value for anchor for the situation like this. anchor takes only like pagestart,pageend and blablabla. in here i think we cant use them right?

Comment: The default values for `anchor` and `fill` work quite well most of the time, however they are useful to further customize the behavior of each component. For example, if you want a JTextField to be as wide as it can (`fill=HORIZONTAL`), or if you want it to be touching the right margin instead of the left margin (`anchor=LINE_END`)...

Answer (score 0):

From the official tutorial:

> Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for weightx or weighty, all the components clump together in the center of their container.

So you just need to set:

```
c.weightx=1.0;
c.weighty=1.0;
```

Also you might want to set some values to anchor and fill.

The default values for anchor and fill work quite well most of the time, however they are useful to further customize the behavior of each component. For example, if you want a JTextField to be as wide as it can `c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, or if you want it to be touching the right margin instead of the left margin `c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LINE_END`...